# Cannot convert 16 digit number to human readable date

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have read a large csv file into a Jupyter notebook, and it contains a column of 16 digit numbers (e.g. 1352160000000000) as an Epoch/Unix timestamp.

I have checked this number on an online Epoch/Unix timestamp converter site and it returns the time I know it should (GMT: Tuesday, November 6, 2012 12:00:00 AM).

I then used the following code (adapted from other answers to this question on this site): `df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], unit='u')` to convert this number to human readable form in my data frame but I either get an error, or I get (1970-01-16 15:36:00.000).

Can anyone point out to me where it is I am going wrong, and what I am missing?

Comment: On Linux, I get `Die Aug 30 01:00:00 CET 42850214` for that timestamp... The correct timestamp is `date -d @1352160000`. So you have to divide it by 1M first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use 'us' unit.

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'], unit='us')

pd.to_datetime(1352160000000000,unit='us')
Out[24]: Timestamp('2012-11-06 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works much more neatly than my work around of first dividing the entire column by 1,000,000 and then setting 'unit='s''.

Answer (score 2):

The `unit` is *microseconds*, so you should use `'us'` as `unit`:

```
pd.to_datetime(1352160000000000, unit='us')
```

for example:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(1352160000000000, unit='us')
Timestamp('2012-11-06 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. As mentioned above it worked much better than my workaround.